# Matching files based on one column

Tags: python, match, matching

I have data in the form"

```
rsID          MAF
rs1980123     0.321
rs870123      0.142
rs314234      0.113
rs723904      0.022
rs1293048     0.098
rs1234123     0.314
rs239401      0.287
rs0928341     0.414
rs9038241     0.021
rs3801423     0.0712
rs8041239     0.312
```

This file is about 2,000 rows long. I have another data file in the form. This file is about 7 million rows:

```
rsID          iHS          Fst          MAF
rs701234      1.98         0.11         0.098
rs908341      1.32         0.31         0.189
rs101098      0.315        0.08         0.111
rs100981      0.093        0.123        0.023
rs7345123     0.481        0.20         0.479
rs090321      1.187        0.234        0.109
rs512341      1.89         0.092        0.324
```

I would like to make rsID's to the first column based on if their MAF is within +/- 0.05 of each other. The rsID column comes from the first data and then a matching column comes from the second data. These match based on +/- MAF 0.05. The output would look like:

```
rsID         match
rs1980123    rs512341
rs870123     rs101098
rs314234     rs090321
rs723904     rs100981
rs1293048    rs701234
```

I would actually like the output to look like (with 5,000 columns):

```
rsID     match1     match2     match3
...      ...        ...        ...
...      ...        ...        ...
...      ...        ...        ...
```

I would like it to be as random as possible so that match1 isn't better than match 5000. How can I do this?

Comment: Can you share what you've tried already?

Comment: This script was written by someone else and I'm told it does what I want, but I don't know how to customize it for my data and what I need to change: http://www.broadinstitute.org/~towfique/selection/scripts/snp-match/plink_matched_SNPs.py

Comment: Why stop at 5,000 matches?

Comment: To ensure that I get 100% matches. It's not guaranteed that each of these has 5,000 matches, let alone wayyy more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hopefully this gives you a good start.  I've just called the files `file1` and `file2`.  Very creative, I know.

```
import random

f1_dict = {}
f2_dict = {}
match_dict = {}
match_threshold = .05
matches_to_return = 2
skip_unmatched = True

isfirstline = True
for line in open("file1"):
    if isfirstline:
            isfirstline = False
            continue
    f1_dict[line.split()[0]] = line.split()[1]

isfirstline = True
for line in open("file2"):
    if isfirstline:
            isfirstline = False
            continue
    f2_dict[line.split()[0]] = line.split()[3]


for i in f1_dict:
    compare_rsID = i
    compare_val = f1_dict[i]
    temp_list = []
    for j in f2_dict:
        if abs(float(f2_dict[j]) - float(compare_val)) <= match_threshold:
            temp_list.append(j)
    match_dict[i] = temp_list

fo = open("output.txt", "wb")
for k in match_dict:
    if skip_unmatched and len(match_dict[k]) == 0:
        continue
    else:
        random.shuffle(match_dict[k])
        fo.write(k),
        for l in match_dict[k][:matches_to_return]:
            fo.write(" ")
            fo.write(l),
        fo.write("\n")
```

I'm certain this can be made more efficient.  It loops through the second dict as many times as there are indices in the first dict.  Also, I've set the number of matches to return to 2 for testing with the tiny datasets in the question.  You can make that 5,000 or whatever else you like.  The elements in the lists are not randomized, but I also have not imposed any order beyond the natural building of the list.  (Edit:  No longer true... it shuffles the lists now.)  I've also variablized the match threshold in case you want to explore other values a little.

Comment: gave you best answer just because of creativity, I'm going to test it out now, and see if it works

Comment: what is the output file?

Comment: Ok, edited it.  Now it sends to "output.txt" in the same directory as the script.  Alter as needed.

Comment: Awesome, thanks so much man! Have you run it yourself? I'm running it on a cluster right now with 8gb and 16 nodes, and it's still going after 7 minutes

Comment: Oy... wow.  I've only run it on the tiny dataset you posted.  But, yes, I would expect it to consume a fair amount of memory and CPU.  You could end up with an array containing a couple thousand lists which each contain up to a couple million elements.  I didn't think much in that direction.  As an alternative, what if we didn't bother adding to a list once it has 5,000 elements?  It would bias your results toward the start of your dataset, but might be a lot faster.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86639/discussion-between-evan-and-andrew).

Answer (score 1):

Here's something I think does what you want in a fairly efficient manner, so hopefully scale-up pretty well. You didn't say what version of Python you're using, so it's written to work with version 2.x. The field delimiter used to create the output file is a variable, so that can easily be changed.

The number of matches isn't limited to 5,000 — it will find them all — but enforcing a limit could be added, if it's really necessary.

```
from collections import defaultdict

TOLERANCE = 0.05
DELIM = '\t'

ref_dict = {}
with open('second_file.txt', 'rt') as inf:
    next(inf)  # skip header row
    for line in inf:
        fields = line.split()
        ref_dict[fields[0]] = float(fields[3])  # rsID to MAF

matches = defaultdict(list)
with open('first_file.txt', 'rt') as inf:
    next(inf)  # skip header row
    for line in inf:
        fields = line.split()
        rsID, MAF = fields[0], float(fields[1])
        for ref_id, ref_value in ref_dict.iteritems():
            if abs(MAF-ref_value) <= TOLERANCE:
                matches[rsID].append(ref_id)

# determine maximum number of matches for output file header row
longest = max(map(len, (v for v in matches.itervalues())))

with open("output.txt", "wt") as outf:
    outf.write('rsId' + DELIM + DELIM.join('match%d' % i
                                        for i in xrange(1, longest+1)) + '\n')
    fmt_str = '{}' + DELIM + '{}\n'
    for k,v in matches.iteritems():
        outf.write(fmt_str.format(k, (DELIM.join(v))))
```

Contents of `output.txt` generated from the sample data shown in your question (`»` represents tab characters):

```
rsId»   match1» match2» match3» match4
rs870123»   rs908341»   rs090321»   rs701234»   rs101098
rs9038241»  rs100981
rs1234123»  rs512341
rs1293048»  rs090321»   rs701234»   rs101098
rs723904»   rs100981
rs1980123»  rs512341
rs3801423»  rs090321»   rs701234»   rs101098»   rs100981
rs8041239»  rs512341
rs239401»   rs512341
rs314234»   rs090321»   rs701234»   rs101098
```

Comment: Thank! I am looking for each row to be 5,000 and no row to be better than the other. The other guy came up with a good idea of shuffling the second file and then matching the first 5000 to a row. Reshuffling the second file and then matching the first 5000 to the second row and so on. I like that idea, but it would be optimal if there was sampling without replacement, does yours do that?

Comment: This doesn't bother randomizing things because it's dictionary based. The contents of a dictionary are naturally unordered, so there no need. As for sampling without replacement: What this does is read each line of the first file and then finds _everything_ in the second file that has an `MAF` within the tolerance. If you want to limit that to no more than 5,000, I can easily add it.

Comment: If you limit it to 5,000. Then do those 5,000 not get used for the next row? Or do they continue to get used but they are just not likely to be the same because it's a dictionary?

Comment: No they don't get used for the next. The results for a row have nothing to do with any other — they're the `rsID`s of the all items in the second file that that have an `MAF` value within the tolerance of the one being processed from the first file. There could be more than 5,000. If there is, a random sample of them could be extracted and output.